# How to monitor input and output HTTP requests on Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, logging

When I invoke an URL I get in an infinite loop due to "301 Move Permanently" HTTP Response Code.

I'd like know the output and input requests that the machine is sending/receiving.

Is there any way to get this info?

The machine is a RHEL 5.5

Comment: tcpdump or wireshark would work for that

Comment: `301` is *moved permanently*. `302` is *found*. Both are not errors but HTTP status codes that are used for redirects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to enable extended logs in the web service to log all input/output requests. Please check official [mod_dumpio](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dumpio.html) module documentation for Apache.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of following two things you can take help of.

1. httpd logs setup in your apache config, commonly found in /etc/httpd/logs
2. tcpdump

> tcpdump -vvvnn port 80 and host ip_addr_of_client -i any

where ip_addr_of_client is host from which you are accessing the url.